# Flutter Dio or http.MultipartRequest post Http status error [301] uploading an Image

Tags: flutter, image, dart, upload, http-status-code-301

I´m working my first project in flutter. I have a web server with mysql, and I'm loading and sending there the data with REST API PHP.
Now I have an upload folder located here:
https:///wp-content/my_app/avatars

In flutter on Android or iPhone, I take a photo from user library, and I want upload that file to my avatars folder in the server.

I need to send the image file (jpg or other) to the server. I find several explanations about how to do it, I wrote the code in 3 different ways:

- http.Request
- Dio
- http.MultipartRequest('POST', httpsUri)

Everytime it give me a 301 error and I can´t understand why.

I think and important thing is that my website is hosted with cloudfare.
I also gave it a try, thinking there was a problem with access permission to the directory, setting the access permission flags to 777 for a few minutes, but that didn't solve it.

This is my code

First of all an extract for code for image filePath

```
// Extract from the source code
XFile? imageFile;
    imageFile = await picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    _pathAvatar = imageFile!.path;
    updateUser(_pathAvatar);


// Upload function

 uploadImage(String filePath) async {

 dio = new Dio();

        var url = "https://<my web site>/upload";
        // API CODE is like : 7940e6b5-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-6883ab87a566
        var token = "<string with my APP API code>";
        Map<String, String> headers = {
          'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
          "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
        };
        await dio.post(url,
            data: filepath,
            options: Options(
                method: 'POST',
                headers: headers,
                responseType: ResponseType.json // or ResponseType.JSON
            )).whenComplete(() {
          print('uploaded');
        }).catchError((onError) {
          print(onError);
        });
```

This is Dio Error:

*DioException [bad response]: This exception was thrown because the response has a status code of 301 and RequestOptions.validateStatus was configured to throw for this status code.
The status code of 301 has the following meaning: "Redirection: further action needs to be taken in order to complete the request"
Read more about status codes at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status
In order to resolve this exception you typically have either to verify and fix your request code or you have to fix the server code.*

DETAIL

```html
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="<my web site>">here</a>.</p>
</body></html>
```

and this is the full HEADER

*connection: keep-alive
alt-svc: h3=":443"; ma=86400

**//in this header I have found / at the end of "location", but I didn't have it  on my url!**

location: https://www.mywebsite.com/wp-content/my_app/avatars**/**

date: Sun, 10 Mar 2024 18:14:05 GMT
transfer-encoding: chunked
strict-transport-security: max-age=16000000
nel: {"success_fraction":0,"report_to":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
cf-ray: 8625484e8c9e2ba2-FRA
report-to: {"endpoints":[{"url":"https://a.nel.cloudflare.com/report/v3?s=Ncs56WKcsVkdO%2F1Dk4ZmDM3Ysc%2FWYFuJ68ESqzSQdJtJTkNH54uqSGxi9cQHSysaAUsffg%2BTbA2zuy0%2FGSq5zBUH8ksxdIFXCIQmqGARb0Q%2FIkJXfnYsgiM8zjIr0xOrhYZzD4ZotA%3D%3D"}],"group":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
cf-cache-status: DYNAMIC
content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
server: cloudflare*

Comment: Try to change the URI to https://<my web site>/upload/

Comment: Thank you, I have already made also this test (I forgot to write it). Adding / to the end of URI, the error is 404 - NOT FOUND.

Comment: Are you able to upload a file using this URI and sending the request using a tool like Postman?

Comment: Thanks you again. This is my first app, and I never used tools like this Postman. So I will search on the web how to use it, and take some tests. I will write here back after these tests.